# Erroring in my Perl script coming from CAM::PDF::Annot module. Don't know why

Tags: perl, pdf, annotations, cpan

I believe this may be a bug in the module I am using, or I am just completely overlooking something.

My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::Annot;

sub main()
{
   my $pdf = CAM::PDF::Annot->new( 'b.pdf' ); 
   my $otherDoc = CAM::PDF::Annot->new( 'b_an.pdf' );
   my $page = 1;
   my %refs;

   my @list = @{$pdf->getAnnotations($page)};
   for my $annotRef (@list){
       $otherDoc->appendAnnotation( $page, $pdf, $annotRef, \%refs);
   } 

   $otherDoc->output('pdf_merged.pdf');
}
exit main;
```

This code was taken almost directly from the synopsis found on the module's CPAN page: [http://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF::Annot](http://metacpan.org/pod/CAM%3a%3aPDF%3a%3aAnnot)

**The problem comes when** I run the script using TWO pdf's with annotations. Using two pdf's without annotations runs. Using one pdf with annotations, and one pdf without annotations, runs. Only when both pdf's have annotations does it error.

**The error is**: "Can't use string ("46") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/CAM/PDF/Annot.pm line 195"

Line 195 of Annot.pm is:

```
push @{$annots->{value}}, $pupRef;
```

Annot.pm is inside the CAM::PDF::Annot module.

Any guidance in fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. In the error, "string ("x")", x is always a number, and seems to change depending on the pdf and the annotations within the pdf. 
And I will try to add any other information that you need to help figure this out!

Comment: `use Carp::Always` to get a more helpful stacktrace.

Comment: Samuel, maybe a silly question, but did you try both the annotated PDFs in the version 'one pdf with annotations and one PDF without annotations'? This to ensure that the problem is not perhaps with the PDF but indeed with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have a problem with a CPAN module, I go to its webpage to try and assess its quality and see if any bugs have already been reported.

[http://search.cpan.org/~donatoaz/CAM-PDF-Annot-0.06](http://search.cpan.org/~donatoaz/CAM-PDF-Annot-0.06/) shows the following suspicious results:

```
CPAN Testers PASS (2)   FAIL (168)   NA (49)
```

It is surprising that you were able to install the module.  No one has reported bugs, but there is clearly a major problem with the code.  It seems the author is either unaware of the tester reports (which have been sent to his CPAN email address for more than a year), or has stopped maintaining it.

You could submit a bug report, so at least others will be aware of your issue.

I realize this does not answer your question of how to fix the problem, but even if you do identify a fix, the author may not apply it (in which case, someone could start the process of becoming a co-maintaner).

Comment: I messed around with this when I saw those errors and found that the tests contain a file path for Windows that won't work on *nix type systems. I need to get time to submit a patch with File::Basename. Seeing the error in the tests made me think this module might run on Windows, but hasn't been test on other OSs. The docs also note that not all annotations are supported.

Comment: Back from the dead... I think I relayed the maintenance of the module to @szabgab back in 2014. This was developed as a quick hack for the company I worked at, on windows platform and for a certain subset of PDF versions. I'll be glad to help again now that I have some time to spare.